# section name only for inner structure, invisible in final document

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex, structure, sections

I just started out using LaTeX and wondered, if there is a (simple) way to name a section without any occurrence in the final text (not as heading nor in TOC). I merely want the section name for the structure tree within LaTeX. e.g.:

```
...

\maketitle
\section*{Disclaimer} % <- this should only appear in the structrue tree of the editor
disclaimer text       % <- this should be visible in the final document

\tableofcontents

\chapter{some chaptername}
...
```

Comment: Should the "Disclaimer" text be visible just in the code or do you have something luke a structure tree in your editor where you want it to show up?

Comment: I use the "LaTeX" Workshop" extension in vscode, which displays a tree-like "STRUCTURE" drop down menu. the tree-structure consists of all the chapters, sections asf. so yes i want it to show up there